# Sencha Touch, MessageBox changing defaults

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, messagebox

```
Ext.Msg.show({
     title: 'Validation',
     message: message,
     height: 300,
     scrollable: true,
     buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
});
```

I'm having a problem with this bit of code. For this particular message box I want the height to be 300 and scrollable to be true because message is quite large. However after this is called any message box (confirm, alert, prompt) seem to inherit both the height and scrollable values which I do not want.

I looked at the code for the show() method for Ext.Msg and it looks like anything that gets passed through to config ie all the parameters in the code above get merged into the default configuration for all Ext.Msg objects. That seems to happen with this line:

```
config = Ext.merge({}, this.defaultAllowedConfig, config);
```

I tried looking for a method that would allow me to reset all the default values back to their defaults after calling show but it doesn't look like I can. Using

```
Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.height = [some number];
```

doesn't work for two reasons, First defaulAllowedConfig is only used when there isn't a defaulted value already for any particular message being shown ie prompt alert or confirm. Second the default height as displayed by the Sencha docs is set to 'auto' which is not a valid value to pass in this statement.

Does anyone know a way around this? I'm sorry it's a long-ish post but I'm completely stuck right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by creating new instance of `Ext.MessageBox` for your customized message box instead of using `Ext.Msg` singleton.

Then your code could look like this:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.MessageBox').show(
        {
            title: 'Validation',
            message: message,
            height: 300,
            scrollable: true,
            buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
        }        
    );
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you! Could you explain a bit why you have to create a new instance? I feel like if you have to create a new instance for every 'custom' message you what which would mean that you could potentially use up a lot of memory correct?

Comment: Its because singleton applies configuration provided in show method to itself. So next time when you call `show` method with less config params singleton is still configured by some properties provided in previous `show` method call. For me it looks like a bug in sencha touch... I think that creating new instance don't use much more memmory because if you don't store reference to this message box and just show it, garbage collector should automatically destroy it after message box is closed.

Comment: Viewport actually holds on to these instances which is less than ideal. It seems that garbage collection doesn't hit them.

Comment: I was about to kill my self with this problem. Thanks dude, may all the good programming spirits be with you.